# Magento install B2B module causing issues

Tags: magento2, module, b2b

I am trying to install the module B2B module in my commerce Magento project. However, I am getting the below error.

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

> Problem 1
>
> - Installation request for magento/module-checkout == 100.2.5.0 -> satisfiable by magento/module-checkout[100.2.5].
>
>   - magento/extension-b2b 1.1.2 requires magento/module-checkout-address-search-negotiable-quote 100.1.0 ->
>     satisfiable by
>     magento/module-checkout-address-search-negotiable-quote[100.1.0].
>   - magento/module-checkout-address-search-negotiable-quote 100.1.0 requires magento/module-checkout 100.3.2 -> satisfiable by
>     magento/module-checkout[100.3.2].
>   - Conclusion: don't install magento/module-checkout 100.3.2
>   - magento/extension-b2b 1.1.1 requires magento/module-shared-catalog 100.1.1 -> satisfiable by
>     magento/module-shared-catalog[100.1.1].
>   - magento/module-shared-catalog 100.1.1 requires magento/module-user 101.1.1 -> satisfiable by
>     magento/module-user[101.1.1].
>   - Conclusion: don't install magento/module-user 101.1.1
>   - Can only install one of: magento/module-user[101.1.0, 101.0.3].
>   - Can only install one of: magento/module-user[101.1.0, 101.0.3].
>   - Can only install one of: magento/module-user[101.0.3, 101.1.0].
>   - magento/module-shared-catalog 100.1.0 requires magento/module-user 101.1.0 -> satisfiable by
>     magento/module-user[101.1.0].
>   - magento/extension-b2b 1.1.0 requires magento/module-shared-catalog 100.1.0 -> satisfiable by
>     magento/module-shared-catalog[100.1.0].
>   - Installation request for magento/extension-b2b ^1.1 -> satisfiable by magento/extension-b2b[1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2].
>   - Installation request for magento/module-user == 101.0.3.0 -> satisfiable by magento/module-user[101.0.3].
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original
> content.

Can anyone have an idea about this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're probably trying to use the wrong version. You should just be able to `composer install magento/extension-b2b` and just let Composer deal with the dependencies.

Comment: If i tried that,i am getting below error

composer install magento/extension-b2b

Invalid argument magento/extension-b2b=^1.1. Use "composer require magento/extension-b2b=^1.1" instead to add packages to your composer.json.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're having issues with dependencies, running these commands might solve it.

```
composer require magento/extension-b2b
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
bin/magento cache:clean
```